# c++ constructor not working - multiple errors

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to make a simple person class with a name, location, sex, and age with a constructor and a method for printing the info out. I'm getting the following warning:

`Warning C26495  Variable 'person::age' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6`

It looks like I have it initialized. Also, when I run the code nothing prints because nothing is saved in my object. Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class person {//class (public: makes it usable within program)
public:
    string name;
    string location;
    string sex;
    int age;

    person(string name, string location, string sex, int age) {//constructor
        name = name;
        location = location;
        sex = sex;
        age = 0;
    }
    void printinfo() {
        cout << "name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "location: " << location << endl;
        cout << "sex: " << sex << endl;
        cout << "age: " << age << endl;

    }
};

int main()
{
    person person1 ("James", "NYC", "Male", 0);
    person1.printinfo();

    system("pause>0");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function arguments *shadow* the class members. You will want to name them differently.

For example:

```
class person {
  public:
    string name_;
    string location_;
    string sex_;
    int age_;

    person(string name, string location, string sex, int age) {
        name_ = name;
        location_ = location;
        sex_ = sex;
        age_ = 0;
    }
};
```

Or, use `this->name` to refer to the class member variable.

Comment: It would be better to use a constructor member initializer list. In your solution, `string` members will be first default-initialized and then assigned-to, which might require more work at the machine code level than a single initialization.

Comment: @DanielLangr: Sure. But that also is just more information to overload the asker with.

Comment: Or, instead of renaming the class members, prefixing them with "this->" should do the trick.

Comment: @Spray'n'Pray: Already have that in the answer.